# Python, Four-bar linkage angle-time plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the angle vs. time plot for the output angle of a four-bar linkage (angle `fi4` in the image below). This angle is calculated using the solution from the https://scholar.cu.edu.eg/?q=anis/files/week04-mdp206-position_analysis-draft.pdf, page 23.

I'm now trying to plot the `fi_4(t)` plot and am getting some strange results. The diagram displays the input angle `fi2` as blue and output angle `fi4` as red. Why is the `fi2` fluctuating over time? Shouldn't the `fi4` have some sort of sine curve?

Am I missing something here?

Four-bar linkage:

[image]

The code:

```
from __future__ import division
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Input
#lengths of links (tube testing machine actual lengths)
a = 45.5   #mm
b = 250   #mm
c = 140   #mm
d = 244.244  #mm

# Solution for fi2 being a time function, f(time) = angle
f = 16.7/60    #/s
omega = 2 * np.pi * f   #rad/s

t = np.linspace(0, 50, 100)
y = a * np.sin(omega * t)
x = a * np.cos(omega * t)

fi2 = np.arctan(y/x)

# Solution of the vector loop equation
#https://scholar.cu.edu.eg/?q=anis/files/week04-mdp206-position_analysis-draft.pdf
K1 = d/a
K2 = d/c
K3 = (a**2 - b**2 + c**2 + d**2)/(2*a*c)
A = np.cos(fi2) - K1 - K2*np.cos(fi2) + K3
B = -2*np.sin(fi2)
C = K1 - (K2+1)*np.cos(fi2) + K3
fi4_1 = 2*np.arctan((-B+np.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C))/(2*A))
fi4_2 = 2*np.arctan((-B-np.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C))/(2*A))

# Plot the fi2 time diagram and fi4 time diagram
plt.plot(t, np.degrees(fi2), color = 'blue')
plt.plot(t, np.degrees(fi4_2), color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

Diagram:

[image]

Comment: your linespace is probably too fast to show the sine curves. Try `t = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)` perhaps? Also, tongue-in-cheek: Φ is spelled "phi" in English, but your angles are θ which is spelled "theta".

Comment: you are correct, I increased the step number and the oscillations went away. The problem is that the shape of the fi4 curve is not correct. Or in other words, I suspect the "jumps" on the fi2 curve when the angle goes from 180 to - 180 degrees influence the fi4 curve which should be smooth.

Comment: also, I'm doubting your math a little -- there shouldn't be a discontinuity in θ_4 when θ_2 goes around 360 degrees to 0.

Comment: yes, this exactly. I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: well, I would recommend to double-check your transcription into code of the document you cite. Then, I would scrutinize the document itself (never take anything for granted). You can solve it yourself using first principles.

Comment: yeah, that was due to using `np.arctan(y/x)`: that loses the info of which quadrant the angle should be in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `linespace(0, 50, 100)` is too fast. Replacing it with:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
```

Second, all the calculations involving the bare `np.arctan()` are incorrect. You should use [`np.arctan2(y, x)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html), **which determines the correct quadrant** (unlike anything based on `y/x` where the respective signs of `x` and `y` are lost). So:

```
fi2 = np.arctan2(y, x)  # not: np.arctan(y/x)

...

fi4_1 = 2 * np.arctan2(-B + np.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C), 2*A)
fi4_2 = 2 * np.arctan2(-B - np.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C), 2*A)
```

Putting some labels on your plots and showing both solutions for `θ_4`:

```
plt.plot(t, np.degrees(fi2) % 360, color = 'k', label=r'$θ_2$')
plt.plot(t, np.degrees(fi4_1) % 360, color = 'b', label=r'$θ_{4_1}$')
plt.plot(t, np.degrees(fi4_2) % 360, color = 'r', label=r'$θ_{4_2}$')
plt.xlabel('t [s]')
plt.ylabel('degrees')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

With these mods, we get:

[image]

Comment: you are correct, I increased the step number and the oscillations went away. The problem is that the shape of the fi4 curve is not correct. Or in other words, I suspect the "jumps" on the fi2 curve when the angle goes from 180 to - 180 degrees influence the fi4 curve which should be smooth.

Comment: thanks for this. I suspected something was not ok with my math but didn't have any idea where to start. I should have looked into the definition of atan function.

Answer (score 3):

BTW, do you want to see an amazingly lazy way of solving problems like these?  Much more inefficient than your code, but much easier to derive (e.g. for other structures) without trying to express the closed form of your solution:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def polar(r, theta):
    return r * np.array((np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)))

def f(th34, th2):
    th3, th4 = th34  # solve simultaneously for theta_3 and theta_4
    pb_23 = polar(a, th2) + polar(b, th3)  # point B based on links a, b
    pb_14 = polar(d, 0) + polar(c, th4)  # point B based on links d, c
    return pb_23 - pb_14  # error: difference of the two

def solve(th2):
    th4_1 = np.array([fsolve(f, [0, -1.5], args=(th2_k,))[1] for th2_k in th2])
    th4_2 = np.array([fsolve(f, [0, 1.5], args=(th2_k,))[1] for th2_k in th2])
    return th4_1, th4_2
```

Application:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
th2 = omega * t
th4_1, th4_2 = solve(th2)

twopi = 2 * np.pi
np.allclose(th4_1 % twopi, fi4_1 % twopi)
# True

np.allclose(th4_2 % twopi, fi4_2 % twopi)
# True
```

Depending on the structure of your mechanism (e.g. 5 links), you may have more than two solutions, and of course more angles, so you'd have to adapt the code above. But you get the idea.

Be warned: `fsolve` iterates to find a suitable (close enough) solution, so as I said, it is much slower than your closed form.

**Update** (some clarification/explanation):

- The function `f` computes the position of the point `B` in two different ways (via `R2-R3` and via `R1-R4`) and returns the difference (as a vector). We solve for the difference to be zero.
- That function takes two arguments: one 2-dimensional *variable* (`th34`, which is an array `[th3, th4]`) and one *parameter* `th2`; the parameter is constant during one run of `fsolve`.
- The values `[0, -1.5]` and `[0, 1.5]` are initialization values (guesses) for `th34` (`th3` and `th4`). We call `fsolve` twice to get the two possible solutions.
- All angles refer to your figure. I use `th` for **θ** (theta, not phi), but I kept along the original `fi4_1` and `fi4_2` for comparison.
- Modulo `2*pi`, `th4_1` should be equal to `fi4_1` etc., which is tested by `np.allclose` to account for numerical rounding errors.

Comment: interesting. please, correct me if I'm wrong; the f function takes 2 arguments, and returns the difference between 2 different ways of calculating the coordinates of B. We want the difference to be close to zero, right? solve function; why is the range of f [0, 1.5] and [0, -1.5]? What is th2_k? allclose; is the fi4_1 the approximate solution?

Comment: @user2882635: I added some explanations; basically: yes, correct that we solve for the difference of various ways to compute `B`, to be 0.

Comment: thanks for more info. what about th2_k? this is an argument for the fsolve, what does it do?

Comment: `th2_k` is each single `θ_2` during the iteration (we apply `fsolve` for each individual angle). `th2` is the array of angles and is simply `ωt`.